# use ingress path for accessing a service from within the kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, kube-dns, ambassador

I am getting my hands dirty with kubernetes and ingress and have seem to have hit bit of a hurdle. So I have a cluster set up and have my services deployed and exposed via `service` and they all are reachable from within the cluster using their names and namespace prefix if necessary. Next I have used ambassador Api gateway as basic `ingress controller` to make these services externally reachable and used a single Authorization service to perform authorization at the gateway and all services are reachable from outside the cluster using their external paths. My problem arises when I have cross service communication that requires authorization to be performed and for that I require that service A calls service B with its external url/ingress defined path and that is where the problem occurs because from within the cluster that path is reported as unreachable. I can call service B from service A using the internal cluster name but then I lose the edge authorization performed at the gateway. Need help as to whether this is default behavior or not and what can be done in this scenario.